# TypeScript - Cannot find name 'process'

Tags: typescript, npm, types

I created a new npm project with npm init. I have typescript and ts-node installed globally. I also installed @types/node to my devDependencies, but I still get a problem "Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node`.ts(2580)".

Any ideas on why this is happening?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With `@types/node` it should work. So the issue comes from the rest of your configuration. Why `ts-node`? Have you a `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @types/node worked fine, I had to restart VS Code, that was the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will solve your work:

```
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem like this, "Reload Window in VS Code:

In order to do this in VS Code, you do `Ctrl+Shift+P` and `Reload Window`.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you installed Node types:

```
$ npm install @types/node --save
```

Now add this line at the top of your file:

```
/// <reference types="node" />
```

But this is what you'll get in the end:

[image]

This happens because your code is executed *in the browser*, not on the server! And the browser has no Node APIs.

So just stop, don't try to have "process" in your code :)

Comment: I was getting the error: error "TS2580: Cannot find name 'module'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node`", despite having already installed the Node types. This solution worked for me but I don't understand why it was necessary.  I also didn't receive the error in the attached image so I don't understand the "so don't" comment :(.

Comment: @kpg because this code is going to be executed in the browser. And the browser does not have any "process" variable: because, well, it's not executed on the server. So you shouldn't add any Node dependencies there: the browser won't have it anyway :)